Ansible playbook or ansible adhoc command to update the X11 forwarding on all linux servers
I new to ansible and looking to develop ansible playbook or ansible adhoc command to disable the X11 forwarding option in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file for a number of ssh servers.
I do not know much about ansible and expecting all SSH servers will be updated with one command or ansible playbook
Any help would be appreciated?

Does How to cleanly edit sshd_config for basic security options in an ansible playbook? or Ansible replacing a value in sshd_config or Ansible to update sshd config file or many more here on SO answer your question?

yeah, I saw a couple of this mentioning about using lineinfile module, I was thinking to use adhoc command as one-off if it is available.

According "will be updated with one command or ansible playbook" you've asked for a playbook. But of course, "I was thinking to use ad-hoc command as one-off if it is available.", an ad-hoc command with module shell or command and sed -i could be possible.
